# Android intent handle multiple identical actions in the same activity

Tags: android, intentfilter

Like Instagram, I need to display multiple choices when a user wants to share a picture to my app. My manifest code is:

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.android.ui.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/intent_chat">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/intent_chat">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>


</activity>
```

This properly display 2 options to the user when trying to share an image or video. One labeled with the application name, the other with `@string/intent_chat`.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to know which one the user chose when handling the incoming `Intent`. I tried using the label, but can't figure out how to access it from the `Intent`.

The other option would be to keep a single `intent-filter` and in my activity display a dialog to have the user specify what he wants to do. However, that implies an additional click, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You shouldn't display two intent-filter in one Activity with same action, try with two different Activities

Comment: Says who? Current recommandation is a single activity application architecture. In which case there is no choice but to display two intent-filters in one activity!

Comment: any luck with this issue?. i am facing this same issue.